# Fastest way to modify openGL texture with openCL per pixel

Tags: opengl, textures, opencl, share

Using OpenGL 4.4 and OpenCL 2.0, lets say i just want to modify specific pixels of a texture per frame.

Which is the optimal way to achieve this?
Which object should i share?
Will i be able to modify only limited number of pixels?
I want GPU only operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there are no OpenCL 2.0 drivers yet; the specification only recently got finalized and implementations probably won't happen until 2014.

Likewise, many OpenGL implementations aren't at 4.4 yet.

However, you can still do what you want with OpenCL 1.2 (or 1.1 since NVIDIA is behind the industry in OpenCL support) and current OpenGL implementations.

Look for OpenCL / OpenGL interop examples, but basically:

1. Create OpenCL context from OpenGL context
2. Create OpenCL image from OpenGL texture
3. After rendering your OpenGL into the texture, acquire the image for OpenCL, run an OpenCL kernel that only update the specific pixel you want to update, and release it back to OpenGL
4. Draw the texture to the screen

Often OpenCL kernels are 2D and address each pixel, but you can run a 1D kernel where each work item updates a single pixel based on some algorithm. Just make sure not to write the same pixel from more than one work item or you'll have a race condition.